# UIPageControl Problem

Tags: iphone

In my application the next page content override by the previous page content show. Please give a sample code that show the detail solution for my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PhotoScroller sample code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PhotoScroller/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010080) and [UIScrollView class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006922).